# mongodb query to show subdocument as maindocument and having pagination with it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

First of all, I have this type of model:

```
const produkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nama_produk: String,
    etalase: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'kategori'},
    kategori: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'kategori'},
    jenis: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'kategori.jenis'},
    bahan: String,
    warna: String,
    deskripsi: String,
    foto_produk: [String],
    harga: Number,
    link_bukalapak: String,
    link_shopee: String,
    link_tokopedia: String,
    link_lazada: String,
    link_website: String,
    display: {type: Boolean, default: false},
}, {
    weights: {
        nama_produk: 5,
    },
    timestamps: true
})

const tokoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, trim: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    merek: String,
    listMerek: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'produk'}],
    deskripsi: String,
    follower: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'user'}],
    email: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true},
    instagram: String,
    whatsapp: String,
    website: String,
    alamat: String,
    foto_profil: String,
    bukalapak: String,
    shopee: String,
    tokopedia: String,
    fotoktp: String,
    banner: [{
        gambar: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        // order: {type: Number, required: true},
    }],
    produk: [produkSchema],
    etalase: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'kategori'}],
    // etalase: [{
    //     kategori: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'kategori'},
    //     order: {Number}
    // }],
    approve: {type: Number, default: 0}, // 0: pending, 1: reject, 2: approve
    populer: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    gambar_populer: [String],
    pilihan: {type: Boolean, default: false},
}, {timestamps: true});
```

and I have an endpoint to filter this `produkSchema` with following code:

```
exports.filterProduk = (req, res) => {
    const {merek, warna, kategori, jenis, hargaAwal, hargaAkhir, skip, limit} = req.body

    let query = {}
    const $and = []

    if (merek) {
        $and.push({$or: merek.map(id => ({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}))})
    }

    if (warna) {
        $and.push({$or: warna.map(warna => ({"produk.warna": warna}))})
    }

    if (kategori) {
        query["produk.etalase"] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(kategori)
    }

    if (jenis) {
        $and.push({$or: jenis.map(id => ({"produk.jenis": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}))})
    }

    if (hargaAwal !== '') {
        query["produk.harga"] = {
            $gte: parseInt(hargaAwal),
        }
    }
    if (hargaAkhir !== '') {
        query["produk.harga"] = {
            $lte: parseInt(hargaAkhir)
        }
    }

    if ($and.length > 0) {
        query = {$and, ...query}
    }

    toko.aggregate([
        {$unwind: '$produk'},
        {$match: query},
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "kategoris",
                as: "produk.etalase",
                let: {pjid: "$produk.jenis"},
                pipeline: [
                    {$unwind: "$jenis"},
                    {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$$pjid", "$jenis._id"]}}},
                    {
                        $project: {
                            "jenis._id": 1,
                            "jenis.label": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {$unwind: {path: "$produk.etalase"}},
        {$group: {_id: '$_id', produk: {$push: '$produk'}, foto_profil: {$first: '$foto_profil'}}},
        {$limit: skip + limit},
        {$skip: skip}
    ])
        .then(async data => {
            res.status(200).json({data, prefix: {produk: "uploads/produk", toko: "uploads/toko"}})
        })
}
```

the actual result is:

```
[
{_id: blabla,
 foto_profil: "blabla",
 produk:[{nama_produk: "blabla", bahan: "blabla", ...rest ProdukSchema as query}]
},
{_id: blabla,
 foto_profil: "blabla",
 produk:[{nama_produk: "blabla", bahan: "blabla", ...rest ProdukSchema as query}]
},
{_id: blabla,
 foto_profil: "blabla",
 produk:[{nama_produk: "blabla", bahan: "blabla", ...rest ProdukSchema as query}]
}
]
```

expected:

```
[
{nama_produk: "blabla", bahan: "blabla", ...rest ProdukSchema as query, foto_profil(from toko schema): "blabla"},
{nama_produk: "blabla", bahan: "blabla", ...rest ProdukSchema as query, foto_profil(from toko schema): "blabla"}
]
```

and having pagination with this `produkSchema` (limit and offset)

actually, before this, I already ask for this query at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429244/joining-collections-sub-subdocument-with-other-collections-subdocument-using-agg?noredirect=1#comment112160467_63429244), but this query will produce a lot of data and need to be paginated,

how do I do this? Should I split my `produkSchema` to main subdocument? or any query exist for this condition?

Comment: @turivishal very nice! Both playground is same as my expected output, but I need the skip and limit for this query, can you update the playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure with exact requirement, but I can guess 2 options,

- Assuming Variables:

```
let skip = 0;
let limit = 10;
```

**First Option:**

- remove `$group` stage from the end and start after `$unwind` stage
- `$replaceRoot` to merge objects `produk` and `foto_profil` using `$mergeObjects` and replace the root

```
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [{ foto_profil: "$foto_profil" }, "$produk"]
      }
    }
  },
  { $skip: skip * limit },
  { $limit: limit }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KpFPMSJ_P5h)

---

**Second Option:**

- remove `$group` stage from the end and start after `$unwind` stage
- `$group` by toko id and produk id, this will group produk and get unique first produk
- `$replaceRoot` to merge objects `produk` and `foto_profil` using `$mergeObjects` and replace the root

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        produk_id: "$produk._id"
      },
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [{ foto_profil: "$root.foto_profil" }, "$root.produk"]
      }
    }
  },
  { $skip: skip * limit },
  { $limit: limit }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fs7M1SiGebv)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do this after lookup:

1. $unwind produk (where the produk still on array type, then unwind it).
2. $group: { _id: nama_produk, etc... }
3. $project ...... or whatever you wanna do with.

so you can get the list of group by nama_produk as an _id.

Comment: Hi @Fair, thanks for answering, but I a little bit confused with your answer. Could you please add the example of code? How about the pagination anyway?

Comment: sorry i did't notice that you already $unwind "produk" on the first line.

the big point is on your $group, you need to fill the "_id" on the "$group" with the key that you want to make main documents.
you wrote that your first fields expected output is "nama_produk", then fill your "_id" on $group with "nama_produk".

Comment: for pagination in mongo is similar with sql base.
on sql base you use offset & limit.
in mongo you use skip & limit. or plus $ sign when you use mongo aggregation. i used to take the value of limit & skip from req.query client, so the backend just send back what client need.